# what all can be represented using data structures

Tags: arrays, data-structures, tree, project

## What all objects can be represented or manipulated using data structures ?

I have been assigned a minor project for my newly started semester in college and have chosen data structures as my topic. But I am finding myself at a loss at getting a task to do as my 'project-work'.

However, I have some knowledge regarding 2D arrays and quad-trees being used to manipulate images (as in compression etc) but I would like to consider some alternatives and get some headers before beginning.

So, I would like to know of any objects (real-world or even virtual) which can be represented or manipulated using data structures or rather any other practical uses of trees, arrays etc so that I can build a strong proficiency in data strucutures (at undergraduate level).

Any sort of headers regarding practical implementation of data strucures are Welcome :).

I am capable of working on C,C++ and Java but I am ready to embrace a new language if the need arises, upto an elementary level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically most programs will have a list of projects to chose from when it comes to such tasks. If you are being asked to define what you have to do you should first identify the following:

- How much time are expected to or willing to devote to the project
- Are you expected to write working programs or is a theoretical analysis sufficient
- Is your own goal to get the highest grade or learning the most (they can be divergent)
- Also realize that data-structures and algorithms are tied at the hip.

A general pattern could be to measure the efficiency of different data-structures which can be used to implement a particular algorithm. Data-structures for manipulating large data-sets including those cases where the entire data can not fit into the RAM is very relevant to what is happening in industry now.

Answer (score 0):

Data structures are essential in the fields of system programming and database software development.

I would suggest looking into different data structures and its optimality for storing small vs large data, heterogeneous vs homogeneous, fast searches, traversals and lookups.

To be really cool, I would write either my own database or in memory operating system implemented only using one or another type of data structure and then reporting on experiences.

Example projects: stack based database, graph oriented file system, ...